# Offline Apple Push Notification Validity

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

If my device don't have internet connection and I have send 100 Push message to my device then how many message I will received after the connection comes online and What is maximum limit of apple push notification if device have no internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to the device when it becomes available.

Only one recent notification for a particular app is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.

For more detail, read **Quality of Service** of [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Comment: But have any specific Hrs/day valididty for Push